# print values in a specific <p>

Tags: php, javascript, html

hello guys? can you help me with this? i want to get the id of the first input and the text value of the second input in a specific **p tag**

```
 <p class="receiveitem">
 <label for="mat_id">Material</label>
 <input type="text" id="4"value="GI Coulping" disabled/>
 <label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>
<input type="text" class="rec_qty" />
 <input type="button" class="receive" value=Receive />
 </p>
 <p class="receiveitem">
 <label for="mat_id">Material</label>
 <input type="text" id="5"value="Vulca Seal" disabled/>
 <label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>
<input type="text" class="rec_qty" />
 <input type="button" class="receive" value=Receive />
 </p>
 <p class="receiveitem">
 <label for="mat_id">Material</label>
 <input type="text" id="6"value="teflon tape" disabled/>
 <label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>
<input type="text" class="rec_qty" />
 <input type="button" class="receive" value=Receive />
 </p>
```

so when i click the receive button that's in the p tag.
it will output someting like

```
ID: 4 and Value: 10
```

already have a js.but i can't get it done.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#receive').click(function(){

    var mat = $('input[type=text]:first').attr('id');
    var qty = $('input[type=text]:last').val;
    alert(mat + qty);
        });
});
```

and i dont know where to put the *this* in my variables mat and qty.please help?

Comment: `id` should be unique, use `class` instead.

Comment: just assuming the user input 10 at second textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified approach using the more semantically correct [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) (which are [broadly supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)) (building on @Chase's answer) ([and a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BK8d/))

```
<p class="receiveitem">
  <label for="mat_id">Material</label>
  <input name="mat_id" type="text" data-id="4" value="GI Coulping" disabled="disabled"/>
  <label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="rec_qty" />
  <input name="rec_qty" type="button" class="receive" value="Receive" />
</p>
<p class="receiveitem">
  <label for="mat_id">Material</label>
  <input name="mat_id" type="text" data-id="5" value="Vulca Seal" disabled="disabled"/>
  <label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="rec_qty" />
  <input type="button" class="receive" value="Receive" />
</p>
<p class="receiveitem">
  <label for="mat_id">Material</label>
  <input name="mat_id" type="text" data-id="6" value="teflon tape" disabled="disabled"/>
  <label for="rec_qty">Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="rec_qty" />
  <input type="button" class="receive" value="Receive" />
</p>
```

With this JavaScript

```
$(document).on("click", "input.receive", function () {
  var mat = $(this).siblings("[name='mat_id']").data("id");
  var qty = $(this).siblings("[name='rec_qty']").val();
  alert("mat id: " + mat + " qty val: " + qty);
});
```

This approach won't abuse the [id attribute](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/) which is designed for node identification and not data storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input#receive', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var qty = $(this).prev().prev('input');
alert(qty);
});
```

You really need to change your markup to use data or unique IDs though.

Comment: its returning object object.